# Trying to learn how to use IndexOf in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, indexof

I just started learning how to use VB.net and I'm trying to figure out how to use the IndexOf method. I thought that I would be able to use it to search for multiple elements within a string but I'm receiving an error that says "Argument matching parameter 'startIndex' narrows from 'String' to 'Integer'" and I'm not sure why. Here is the code I'm using.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim cont As Integer = 0
    Do Until cont = 1
        Dim PlayerChoice As String
        Dim ComputerChoice As String
        Dim ran As New Random
        Dim num As Integer = ran.Next(1, 4)
        Dim PlayerName As String
        Dim check As Integer
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!")
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name.")
        PlayerName = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to choose rock, paper, or scissors?")
        PlayerChoice = Console.ReadLine()
        Do Until check <> -1
            check = PlayerChoice.IndexOf("rock", "paper", "scissors")
            Console.Clear()
        Loop
        Select Case num
            Case 1
                ComputerChoice = "rock"
            Case 2
                ComputerChoice = "paper"
            Case 3
                ComputerChoice = "scissors"
        End Select
        Console.WriteLine(PlayerName & ": " & PlayerChoice)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(750)
        Console.WriteLine("Computer: " & ComputerChoice)
        If PlayerChoice = "rock" Then
            If ComputerChoice = "rock" Then
                Console.WriteLine("There was a tie!")
            ElseIf ComputerChoice = "paper" Then
                Console.WriteLine("The computer wins!")
            ElseIf ComputerChoice = "scissors" Then
                Console.WriteLine("You win, " & PlayerName & "!")
            End If
        ElseIf PlayerChoice = "paper" Then
            If ComputerChoice = "rock" Then
                Console.WriteLine("You win, " & PlayerName & "!")
            ElseIf ComputerChoice = "paper" Then
                Console.WriteLine("There was a tie!")
            ElseIf ComputerChoice = "scissors" Then
                Console.WriteLine("The computer wins!")
            End If
        ElseIf PlayerChoice = "scissors" Then
            If ComputerChoice = "rock" Then
                Console.WriteLine("The computer wins!")
            ElseIf ComputerChoice = "paper" Then
                Console.WriteLine("You win, " & PlayerName & "!")
            ElseIf ComputerChoice = "scissors" Then
                Console.WriteLine("There was a tie!")
            End If
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again?")
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 0 to play again.")
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to quit.")
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
    Loop
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot call `indexof` like that.

if you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.IndexOf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will find out that you **MUST** only search 1 string at a time. in your case you will have to do it 3 time or until you find a match

you can implement an helper method like this

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim test As String = "paper"
        Console.WriteLine(test.IndexOf("rock", "paper", "scissors"))

        test = "rock"
        Console.WriteLine(test.IndexOf("rock", "paper", "scissors"))

        test = "scissors"
        Console.WriteLine(test.IndexOf("rock", "paper", "scissors"))

        test = "foobar"
        Console.WriteLine(test.IndexOf("rock", "paper", "scissors"))

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module

Public Module helper

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IndexOf(ByVal value As String, ParamArray values() As String) As Integer
        Return Array.IndexOf(values, value)
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Dang, that's unfortunate. Thank you for the response!

Comment: @Jason, you can write an helper method that would work like you want

Comment: A helper method? I'm not quite sure what that is.

Comment: Oh! I see now. Thank you very much for the help and patience!

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR, there is many way to do this, you could use linq or a list of string with .contains, hashset and maybe others that i don't remember right now :-)

Comment: Correct, hes using an array so using the array.indexof would suffice and wouldnt require a helper... either way it works.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR, but i agree with you, array.indexof would be a better use here so i updated my code but kept the helper method since he didn't know what it was